# java ScheduledFuture getDelay return negative value

Tags: java, semaphore, scheduledexecutorservice

I am using ScheduledExecutorService, Semaphore and ScheduledFuture to write a rate limiting function, simply put, when a client reaches the limit, server will return error 429 with "msg please try after %d second".
I use scheduledFuture.getDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS) to get value of %d. For the first or second attempts, it acts normal, i.e. allow access unit reach the limit and showing how many seconds to wait afterward. Then getDelay starts showing negative value. Does it mean the ScheduledExecutorService not working properly?
following is the snippet

```
public RateLimiter(int permits, long durationInMillis){
    this.semaphore = new Semaphore(permits);
    this.permits = permits;
    this.durationInMillis = durationInMillis;       
    scheduleReplenishment();
}

public boolean allowAccess() {      
    return semaphore.tryAcquire(); 
}

public long nextReplenishmentTime() {
    return scheduledFuture.getDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}


public void stop() {
    scheduler.shutdownNow();
}   

public void scheduleReplenishment() {
    scheduledFuture = scheduler.schedule(() -> {
        semaphore.release(permits - semaphore.availablePermits());
    }, durationInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the task has done, the `getDelay(TimeUnit)` will be negative. To show it, I add two parameters to `scheduleReplenishment()`, and change `getReplenishmentTime()` to `printReplenishmentTime()`.

Note1: If you create a `Future<>`, and replace one with another, you should care about the deleted one...

Note2: If you want test `Future<>` and `Semaphore`, don't release the allocated resources immediately.

```
private final ConcurrentSkipListMap<String, ScheduledFuture<?>> scheduledFutures
                                    = new ConcurrentSkipListMap<>();
private final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

public void printReplenishmentTime() {

    scheduledFutures.forEach((name, f) -> {

        final long delay = f.getDelay(TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        System.out.println(name + " delay " + delay);
    });
}

/**
 * try acquire one permit once from {@code semaphore}, 
 * then wait {@code waitInMillis}, until all permits used.
 * 
 * @param waitInMillis after successfully used one permit, wait
 * @param permits all permits to use, best if permits @gt; 2
 */
public void scheduleReplenishment(final long waitInMillis, final int permits) {

    final String name = "future" + counter.getAndIncrement();
    scheduledFutures.put(name, scheduler.schedule(() -> {

        try {

            for (int permit = permits; 0 < permit;) {

                final boolean ack = semaphore.tryAcquire(1);
                System.out.println(name + " " + (ack ? "acquire" : "not acquire")
                        + " one, but need " + permit);
                if (ack) {

                    permit--;
                }
                if (0 < permit) {

                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(waitInMillis);
                    } catch (final InterruptedException e) {

                        System.out.println(name + " interrupted, exiting...");
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(name + " done");

        } finally {

            semaphore.release(permits - permit);
        }

        // BAD CODE: semaphore.availablePermits() for debugging purposes
        // only, maybe 0 release...
        // semaphore.release(permits - semaphore.availablePermits());
    }, durationInMillis, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scheduler.schedule()` is a one time go function, that's why it shows negative `getDelay()` value.